# Is learning Rust for Solana worth it, or just use Solidity via Solang for Solana

Tags: ethereum, bitcoin

I recently started learning developing programs, smart contract on Solana network. At this early stage, it is actually tough for me. I am above average in Solidity on EVM based blockchain eg Ethereum, BNB, Polygon etal.

My question is, should I simply stay put to using Solang environment(Solidity) to deploy Solana program, or go harder by learning Rust and using it to deploy solana apps?

Comment: Rust vs Solang for Solana Blockchain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better long term solution is probably to write your programs in rust. The Anchor framework is a great help https://www.anchor-lang.com/ and makes many things easier.

Comment: alright. Thanks. Will try.